# Cast element of character array to integer, and print using cout

Tags: c++

I have something in my opinion unexpected happening here.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    cout << "argv[1] : " << argv[1] << endl;
    cout << "(int)argv[1] : " << (int)argv[1] << endl;
}
```

When I call this:

```
$ ./a.out 1
```

The output is:

```
argv[1] : 1
(int)argv[1] : -1074470344
```

I would expect

```
argv[1] : 1
(int)argv[1] : 49
```

Since the ASCII code for `'1'` is 49.

What is happening here?

Comment: ***Type casting is not magic!!!*** `argv[1]` is a pointer. You are getting the integer value of the pointer. (Why don't you read about type conversions instead of making wrong assumptions, before trying to use them?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that the type of `argv` is `char* argv[]`, so `argv[1]` is not a single `char`, but a C-style string.

To print the first character, use `argv[1][0]`.

```
std::cout << "(int)argv[1][0] : " << (int)argv[1][0] << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 2):

`argv[1]` is not a `char`, it's a `char *`.

`(int)argv[1][0]` may be what you want, if you guarantee the argument will be only one character.

```
cout << "(int)argv[1][0] : " << (int)argv[1][0] << endl;
```

and you will get:

```
argv[1] : 1
(int)argv[1][0] : 49
```

**NOTICE**

If your argument is a string like "11", you will get a strange result such as:

```
argv[1] : 11
(int)argv[1][0] : 49
```

Answer (score 0):

> cout << "(int)argv[1] : " << (int)argv[1] << endl;

You are trying to cast argv[1] which is a char pointer, i.e. "C string". It could also contain "11", not just '1'.

You would need to "cast" the first letter, but I think it is not a good idea either way.

Furthermore, you have not checked against the argc whether you actually supplied the argument on the command line. That is another mistake unless you can make sure somehow it is never "misused".

Yet another mistake is not returning an integer, e.g. zero, at the end of the function since it should, otherwise you will get a warning from your compiler.

You could write this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if (argc == 1)
        return 1;
    cout << "argv[1] : " << argv[1] << endl;
    cout << "(int)argv[1][0] : " << (int)argv[1][0] << endl;
                         ^^^                    ^^^
    return 0;
}
```

That being said, you probably want to use `static_cast` for this in a C++ program rather than low-level C-type cast.